# jQuery's data() [storage object] in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you remember `$(elem).data('somekey', 'somevalue')`, when used NOT for data attributes, but for storing arbitrary values/objects on the jQuery element object? In fact, data() was used to store anything, often entire object instances *on the element*.

It was used a lot and quite handy. Is there any vanilla javascript counterpart? Or, how can that functionality be replicated with vanilla js?

Comment: Here's jQuery's implementation: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/main/src/data/Data.js. It's literally just a POJS object.

Comment: Technically you could easily replace it with `.dataset` on `HTMLElements`. @fdomn-m Man, what a response. Most of jQuery's innovations have now been adopted in javascript, so it's prudent to cut out the middle man, definitely if the middle man is just a wrapper for native functionality that results in more calls upon calls. Why use the alternative if the browser has a _native implementation_? Move with the times. It's not because corporations used it and still have it on holdover, it's something that should still be promoted.

Comment: So? They’re also less overhead. Yeah I know, who cares our computers are powerful now! This is how we got todays mess of frameworks and layers upon layers of function calls. Use an IDE, and you only type two letters anyway. Gonna leave it at that, this is not relevant to the question. Remain in the 2000s all you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQuery object is a sort of wrapper for the native element. You can do the same thing yourself with a standard JavaScript object, making one property the element itself. Then it's just a matter of adding arbitrary properties and acting on them as needed.

```js
const myElObject = {};

myElObject.element = document.querySelector('#myElement');
myElObject.otherProperty = 1;

myElObject.element.textContent = "Some text";

console.log(myElObject);
```

```html
<div id="myElement"></div>
```